# Написание программы для расчета формул (компьютерная алгебра, редактор формул)

Tags: c#, математика, форма, редактор-текста, formula

Существуют специфические задачи для которых известные мне программы типа MathCad и прочее не подходят. В связи с этой задачей возникаю два вопроса:
 1. Как тот же MathCad анализирует введенную информацию? Если написано, например, x = 2 * y то какой существует последующий алгоритм, в следствии которого происходит расчет этого выражения. Создается объект этой формулы или еще как то?
 2. Как в текстовом поле графического интерфейса использовать полноценные формулы? Нужно подключать разметку или что то вроде этого? как это сделать?

Работаю на Visual Studio. Можно ли это на нем реализовать?

Comment: Посмотрите на исходные коды mathcad и его __клонов__

Answer (score 2):

[Однопроходной лексический парсер формул C#](http://www.cyberforum.ru/redirector.php?url=aHR0cCUzQSUyRiUyRnNvdXJjZXMuY29kZW5ldC5ydSUyRmZpbGUlMkYzNzgxJTJGTGVsZWtvLkNhbGNTY3JpcHQuY3Muemlw)

[Синтаксический анализ](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Синтаксический_анализ)